# Solving non-linear set of equations with the same form?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Let's say I have a set of non-linear equations with exactly the same form but different coefficients:
$$ 5xy - 2x + 4y - 2z + 7zy = 3 $$
$$ 3xy - 6x + 7y - 2z + 7zy = 2 $$
$$ 5xy - 1x + 8y - 1z + 3zy = 8 $$

Is there a routine method to solve these sorts of equations, either numerically or in closed form? (Note that I just picked these coefficients at random - my actual example is slightly more complicated and I am aware the system might not have any solutions whatsoever).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even if random, your problem is interesting.

All CAS (**C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem) will do the work using most of the time [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).

The problem is that the results could be far from nice. Using you example with Wolfram Alpha (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%7B5x+y+-+2x+%2B+4y+-+2z+%2B+7z+y+%3D%3D+3%2C3x+y+-+6x+%2B+7y+-+2z+%2B+7z+y+%3D%3D+2%2C5x+y+-+1x+%2B+8y+-+1z+%2B+3z+y+%3D%3D+8%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D)). Just numbers.

Now, make some effort.

From $(1)$, you have $$z=\frac{-5 x y+2 x-4 y+3}{7 y-2}$$ Plug it in $(2)$ and simplify to get
$$y=\frac{1-4 x}{2 x-3}$$

Plug in $(3)$ and obtain (after removing the denominator)
$$184 x^3+492 x^2-648 x+169=0$$

Now, use the method for cubic equations. Three real roots since $\Delta=16840872000$. Using the trigonometric method, they are
$$x_k=\frac{1}{46} \left(14 \sqrt{85} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{21311 }{11662}\sqrt{\frac{5}{17}}\right)\right)\right)-41\right)\quad \text{with} \quad k=0,1,2$$ Frm these, you obtain the exact solutions for the corresponding $y_k$ and $z_k$.

Computing with as many figures as you want
$$x_0=+0.6187464041305912173164358949669614741334674637271\cdots$$
$$x_1=+0.4017961260109958985396689999338839910437998943606\cdots$$
$$x_2=-3.6944555736198479854213222862051932912642238798268\cdots$$

What do you prefer ?